# Can't connect to MySQL installed via Homebrew on Mac Monterey

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, macos-monterey

I ma using M1 MacBook Air, and managing my tools with Homebrew.
I've installed Mysql, and it was working fine for a while, but when I've rebooted my device it just stopped working.

I don't get any errors when running `brew services start mysql`, but when I try `brew services list` MySQL is marked as `stopped`.

When I try to enter mysql with `mysql -u user -p password` I get following error:
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

When I run `mysql.server start` (as some answers suggest) I get following error:
`. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/MacBook-Air.local.pid).`

I've tried many solutions, but non of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this error `The server quit without updating PID` on mysql version 8.0.18

try `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql xx/mysql`, and `sudo chmod 775 xx/mysql`

'xx/mysql' is your mysql home dir

Comment: Hi! Thank's for your idea, I've already fixed it by reinstalling MySQL